# Prevent shell from escaping single quotes

Tags: bash, sh

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh -x
ARGS=""
CMD="./run_this_prog"
. . . 
ARGS="-first_args '-A select[val]' "
. . . 
$CMD $ARGS
```

I want the commandline to be expanded like this when I run this shell script:

```
./run_this_prog -first_args '-A select[val]'
```

Instead what shell does (note the added '\' before each single quote):

```
+ ARGS=
+ CMD='./run_this_prog'
+ ARGS='-first_args '\''-A select[val]'\'' '
```

and what it ran on commandline (escaped every special char - Not what I want):

```
./run_this_prog -first_args \'\-A select\[val\]\'
```

I tried escaping single quotes like :

```
ARGS="-first_args \'-A select[val]\' "
```

But that resulted in (added '\' after each backslash):

```
+ ARGS=
+ CMD='./run_this_prog'
+ ARGS='-first_args \'\''-A select[val]\'\'' '
```

I did my googling but couldn't find anything relevant. What am I missing here?
I am using sh-3.2 on rel6 centOS.

Comment: I think that the shell does what you told it to do. Those additional `\'` you see is just for you to see on screen (as you run `sh -x`). Just on screen. As for what `sh` stores in memory is what you tell it to store, which is already correct, i think. So, `sh` does not "escape" your data, it is just how it shows things on screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once a quote is inside a string, it will not work the way you want: Inside a string quotes are not syntactic elements, they are just literal characters. This is one reason why bash offers arrays.

Replace:

```
#!/bin/sh -x
...
ARGS="-first_args '-A select[val]' "
$CMD $ARGS
```

With:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
...
ARGS=(-first_args '-A select[val]')
"$CMD" "${ARGS[@]}"
```

For a much more detailed discussion of this issue, see: ["I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Also, if you are going to use an array, change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: @chepner Good point.  I just added the shebang to the answer.  Also, thanks for your edit adding the missing quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This helps!

Comment: Now this was a life saver. Thank you.